# C++ problems with string and while statements

Tags: c++

Hi there I'm very new to programing and have made a simple programme for my work, but I'm having a problem once I've ran the programme and it restarts with typing in (y) then that is used for the string when the programme continues going through the lines? Hope I've verbose enough

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    cout << " Battery Size Calculator \n";
    cout << "*************************\n";
    cout << " Made by Jerome Cooper \n\n\n";

    char again = 'Y';

    while (again == 'y' || again == 'Y') {

        string psuname;
        cout << "Enter panel or psu name/address  ";
        getline(cin, psuname);

        int backup_time(0);
        cout << " \n\n Enter backup time in hours ";
        cin >> backup_time;

        double alarm_load(0);
        cout << "\n\n Enter panel load in amps ";
        cin >> alarm_load;

        double alarm_active_load(0);
        cout << " Enter panel load in alarm state in amps  ";
        cin >> alarm_active_load;

        cout << "\n\n\n~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\n\n\n ";

        cout << " Calculation for panel/psu  : ";
        cout << " 1.25 x ((" << backup_time << " x " << alarm_load << ") + 1.75 x (" << alarm_active_load << " x 0.5 ))";

        cout << " \n\n minimum battery size for  " << psuname << "  " << 1.25 * ((backup_time * alarm_load) + 1.75 * (alarm_active_load * 0.5)).<< "aH";
        cout << " \n\n";

        cout << " Do you want todo another calculation (y/n)";
        cin >> again; //change control variable
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use `fflush(stdin)` before `getline`

Comment: @RoQuOTriX Wrong stream, and undefined behavior.

Comment: Reduce your comparisons by using `toupper` or `tolower`. Example:  `(toupper(again) == 'Y')`

Answer (score 3):

When you give input to your program, you end each input by pressing the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key, right? That <kbd>Enter</kbd> key will be added to the input buffer as a newline, `'\n'`.

When you use the stream input extraction with `>>` all white-space (and newline is a white-space character) will be read and discarded. But when you use [`std::getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) it doesn't do that. Instead it will see the newline left in the input buffer from your last extraction (the `'y'`) and think it's an empty line.

You need to ask `std::cin` to skip the newline (and other possible spaces) before you use `std::getline`. This can be easily done with a "trick" by using the [`std::ws`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/ws) manipulator function:

```
// Skip possible leading whitespace, and then read the line
getline (cin >> ws, psuname);
```

Of course, if you *want* `psuname` to contain leading spaces (except the newline) then you need to come up with some other way to skip the newline. For example by [ignoring](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore) the remainder of the line (including the newline) after you read the input for `again`.

Comment: I also have a problem when a letter has been put in when a number should be entered I get a strange loop going on

Comment: @jeromecooper That's a different issue, that should really be asked separately. But to summarize the issue you need to check that each extraction was done properly by checking the state of `std::cin`. For example by `if (cin >> alarm_load) { /* All is okay */ } else { /* Wrong input, handle it some way */ }`. Also remember to clear the `std::cin` state in such cases.

Comment: @jeromecooper Also, it could be useful to read *all* input as lines into strings, then use [`std::istringstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) for the "parsing" of the input. This way the state of `std::cin` will always be okay (unless the user gives the end-of-file input). For this you don't need to skip leading space, as it's done by the extraction from the string stream.

Comment: I find it useful, for tasks like this, to forget about the interactive nature of the program. The program doesn't care that there's a user slowly typing in commands one at a time. You might as well give it a big document with all the commands ready-entered (in fact, you _can_!). Build your I/O operations with this in mind, as if you were simply parsing a big document provided all at once. The fact that in reality your program occasionally gets blocked waiting for the next piece of the document to be provided, should be irrelevant to your logic.

Answer (score 0):

After entering a value for the variable again the new line character still in the input beffre and a next call of the member function `getline` reads an empty string before encounting this new line character.

To avoid the problen you can write

```
    #include <limits>

    //...

    std::cin.ignore( std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n' );
    getline(cin, psuname);
```

Comment: @jeromecooper The was a typo. I updated the code snippet.:)